Discord.py "on_message_edit" method for a message that was sent while a discord bot was offline/after restart
I'm attempting to create a Discord bot (using discord.py) that can extract data from a message containing an editable embed, which receives updates. The bot functions correctly if the bot already present in the server and online when the message with the embed is sent. However, if the bot restarts or loses connection to the server, it does not work properly.
I'm wondering if it's possible for a discord.py bot to utilize the on_message_edit method for a message sent to the channel before the bot joined the server or while the bot was offline.
I've used Channel.history() to direct the bot to specific messages, but on_message_edit still doesn't seem to work. Based on some previous questions that I have seen it is because the messages are not loaded into the bot's cache, but a search of the docs does not appear to have a way to force old messages into the cache but it feels like it should be possible.
In short I think I want something like TextChannel.fetch_message(id), but this does not put the message into the internal cache in my experience.
Thanks in advance for any help you may provide.

For this, you might want to use on_raw_message_edit instead of on_message_edit. on_raw_message_edit is called regardless of the message being in the cache or not.
Keep in mind that this will be called whether or not the message is in the cache so you might not want both on_message_edit and on_raw_message_edit. If the message is found in the cache, then the payload from on_raw_message_edit will have cached_message attribute. Make sure to read the documentation carefully.

Documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_raw_message_edit

